# Polynomials with non integral results for multiples of 10

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

As challenge problem, my teacher challenged us to find a polynomial $f(x)$ that would return an integer for all positive integral values of $x$ except for some (possibly not all) $x$ divisible by $10$. For example, we could have some polynomial $g(x)$ in which $g(1)=1$, but $g(10)=0.1$ and $g(20)=2$. (I'm just making up numbers here.) I've been bashing my head at this, and have tried raising $x$ to the fourth power to eliminate the units digits down to $0,1,5,6$, but have had no such luck. Is this an impossible problem? If not, could I maybe see an example of a such polynomial, and why it would work?

Comment: Could you please clarify 'positive integral values of $x$ **except** for some (possibly not all) $x$ divisible by $10$'?

Comment: For example, the function would accept all positive integers 1-9, 11-19, etc. and return an integer for those, but could or could not return an integer for 10, 20, 30, etc. However, we need it such that at least one of 10, 20, 30, etc. returns a decimal.

Comment: Yes, I thought of perhaps a polynomial along the lines of $f(x)=(x+1)(x+2)...(x+9)/10$ but then realized that $10$ has two factors, both of which cycle in those nine terms, so all integers would have an integral value for that $f(x)$.

Comment: So try a slightly bigger denominator than $10$?

Comment: I'm not sure where to go, as there are always exceptions, so to speak, like when a multiple of a large power of $2$ or $5$ come up, like perhaps $256$ or $625$

Comment: Sorry for the double post, but I think the challenge with approaching it this way is the fact that when dividing out, the multiples of $5$ but not $10$ behave a lot like the multiples of $10$, so in attempting to force a multiple of $10$ to be a decimal with regards to $f(x)$, I'm often also making the multiples of $5$ a decimal as well, which is what I don't want.

Comment: I think it will be impossible to have such $f$ so that $f(x) \not \in \mathbb Z$ when $x \equiv a \pmod{10}$ and $f(x) \in \mathbb Z$ when $x \not \equiv a \pmod{10}$. There should be some restrictions on the subset modulo 10.

Comment: Yes, I think that was what my teacher was getting at when he said that it had to be nonintegral for some, but possibly not all, $x\equiv0(\mod 10)$

Answer (score 5):

A general answer is something like this:

(i) For every prime power $p^k$ there exists a polynomial $f(x)$ such that for every $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, $f(a)$ is an integer if and only if $p^k$ does not divide $a$. For instance, $f(x)=\frac1p \cdot \frac{(x+1)(x+2)\ldots(x+p^k-1)}{(p^k-1)!}$ is such a polynomial.

(ii) If $m$ is a positive integer with at least two distinct prime factors, and $f(x)$ is a polynomial with the property that $f(a)$ is an integer whenever $m$ does not divide $a$, then $f(a)$ is integer for all integers $a$.

To prove (ii) it is sufficient to prove that $f(0)$ is an integer. Let $p$ and $q$ be two distinct prime divisors of $m$. From Lagrange's interpolation we know that $f$ has rational coefficients; take a positive integer $M$ such that $g(x)=Mf(x)$ has integer coefficients.

Then there are some positive integers $M_1$ and $M_2$ such that $M_1M_2=M$, $M_1$ and $M_2$ are coprime, $M_1$ is coprime with $p$ and $M_2$ is coprime with $q$. None of $M_1$ and $M_2$ is divisble by $m$, so $f(M_1)$ and $f(M_2)$ are integers. Hence,
$$ Mf(0) = g(0) \equiv g(M_1) = Mf(M_1) \equiv 0 \pmod{M_1} $$
and similarly
$$ Mf(0) \equiv Mf(M_2) \equiv 0 \pmod{M_2}. $$
Since $M_1$ and $M_2$ are coprime, we get
$Mf(0) \equiv 0 \pmod{M}$, so $f(0)$ is an integer.

---

See also the 2nd problem of RMM2011 at
http://rmms.lbi.ro/rmm2011/_dwl/Sols2011D1.pdf

Comment: Thanks for adding this great answer. Not forgetting about the contest link!! In a way you get away with less technology than Hw Chu. However, I'll let them "keep" the bounty. There isn't that much difference in your two solutions. Also, they have more use for a rep boost (a silly argument, I know, but that's how I feel about it this time). May the OP will accept your answer?

Comment: Hw Chu was first, so your decision is fair. What is "OP"?

Comment: A local acronym: OP = the original poster, or the original post. In this case I referred to user 517672. [A list of such](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3012/common-acronyms-used-on-main-and-meta).

Answer (score 4):

Let me characterize your problem as follows. Let $S \subset \{0, 1, \cdots, 9\}$. We want to see if there is a $f(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$ such that $f(a) \in \mathbb Z$ if and only if $a \equiv a' \pmod{10}$ for some $a' \in S$.

> My conclusion is, such $f(x)$ exists if and only if $S$ satisfies the
>   follows: There is a $S_2 \subset \{0,1\}$ and $S_5 \subset\{0,1,2,3,4\}$
>    such that $a \in S \Leftrightarrow a \pmod2 \in S_2$
>   and $a \pmod5 \in S_5$.

For instance, $S = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ is not admissible but $S = \{1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9\}$ is (pick $f(x) = \frac15(x^4-1)$).

For the only if part, suppose $f(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$ and $F(x) = \alpha_f f(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]$ where $\alpha_f$ is the least positive integer such that $\alpha_f f(x)$ has integral coefficients. For $p = 2$ or $5$ and $m \in \mathbb N$, $F(a) \pmod{p^m}$ is periodic on $a$ with period dividing $p^m$ (because $F(a+p^m) \equiv F(a) \pmod{p^m}$). This means that "whether the $p$-adic valuation $v_p(f(a)) \geq 0$" is periodic on $a$ with the period being $p^{m_p}$ for some $m_p \in \mathbb N_{\geq 0}$. This enforces the only if part.

For the if part, suppose we have an admissible $S$ and the corresponding $S_2$ and $S_5$ are given. We can construct as follows:

Let $F_2(x) = \prod_{a \in S_2}(x-a)$ and $F_5(x) = \prod_{a \in S_5}(x-a)$. From the Chinese Remainder Theorem, there exists a $F(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]$ such that $F(x) \equiv F_5(x) \pmod 5$ and $F(x) \equiv F_2(x) \pmod 2$.Then $f(x) = \frac{1}{10}F(x)$ is what we desired.

---

**Edit (generalizations):** Thanks to user141614's insightful example on the $p^m$ case, we can get a more general result when 10 is replaced by $N$ with factorization $N = p_1^{v_1}p_2^{v_2}\cdots p_r^{v_r}$:

> *Claim:* Let $S \subset \{0,1, \cdots, N-1\}$ be a collection of congruence classes modulo $N$. Then there exists a $f(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$
>   such that $f(n) \in \mathbb Z \Leftrightarrow n \pmod N \in S$,
>   if and only $S$ satisfies the following condition:
>
> There exists $S_1 \in \{0, 1, \cdots, p_1^{v_1}-1\}, \cdots, S_r \in \{0, 1, \cdots, p_r^{v_r}-1\}$
>    such that $n \in S \Leftrightarrow
> > n\pmod{p_i^{v_i}}\in S_i$ for all $1 \leq i \leq r$.

The only if part again follows from the following fact:

> For any $f(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$, "whether the $p_i$-adic valuation
>   $v_{p_i}(f(n)) \geq 0$" is periodic on $n$ with period $p_i^{s_i}$ for
>   some $0 \leq s_i \leq v_i$.

For the if part, we can use the Chinese Remainder Theorem again for the construction. Suppose we have $S$ and $S_i, \cdots, S_r$ defined as above. user141614's post teaches us that $\binom{n}{p_i^{v_i}-1}$ is divisible by $p_i$ if and only if $p_i^{v_i} \ | \ n$. (This can be proved using the closed form formula of $v_p(m!)$).

For each $1 \leq i \leq r$, we can let $u(x) = \prod_{i=0}^{p_i^{v_i}-2}(x-i)$ and $F_{p_i}(x) = \sum_{a \not\in S_i}u(x-a)$. Then we know that $p_i^{1+v_{p_i}((p_i^{v_i}-1)!)} \ | \ F_{p_i}(n) \Leftrightarrow n \pmod{p_i^{v_i}} \in S_i$.

By Chinese Remainder Theorem, there is a $F(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$ such that $F(x) \equiv F_{p_i}(x) \pmod{p_i^{1+v_{p_i}((p_i^{v_i}-1)!)}}$. Then $f(x) = \mathscr N^{-1}F(x)$ is what we desired, where

$$
\mathscr N = N \cdot \prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{v_{p_i}((p_i^{v_i}-1)!)}.
$$

Comment: Can the LCM of the denominators of the polynomial coefficients have prime factors other than $2$ and $5$? For example, $x^5-x$ is divisible by $30$ for each $x\in\mathbb Z$. I see you've looked only at $2$ and $5$ in the "only if" portion, and I think you can claim only that, if an example $p\in\mathbb Q[x]$ of a desired polynomial exists, the denominator of a non-integral $p(x)$ cannot have factors $2$ or $5$. This doesn't mean that it cannot have other factors... Does it make sense?

Comment: By similar arguments as in the only if part, if $f$ is a polynomial such that $3$ showed up in the denominator for some $f(a)$, you will see that there is a positive integer $m$ such that 3 is also in the denominator for all $f(a+k3^m)$. Since 3 is relatively prime to 10, this will cause non-integral values spread throughout all congruent classes.

Comment: Of course... Silly me.

Comment: I may be wrong, but can you specify the difference between this and my previous mentioned attempt with $f(x) = (x+1)(x+2)...(x+9)/10$? Because I think that although this (my polynomial) satisfies the condition in which $f(x)$ has to be integral for all $x\not\equiv 0\pmod {10}$, it also is integral for all multiples of 10 because you can find a factor of two and a factor of five in the cycle of nine that increases.

Comment: Consider $F(x) = (x+1)\cdots(x+9)$. Then $F(n) \pmod 5$ will be 5-periodic with pattern $0,0,0,0,0$ and $F(n) \pmod 2$ will be 2-periodic with pattern $0,0$, so $F(x) \pmod{10}$ is 10-periodic with pattern $0,0,\cdots, 0$. It is the individual periods of $F(x) \pmod{5^m}$ and $F(x) \pmod{2^l}$ which restricts the pattern of $F(x) \pmod{5^m2^l}$.

Comment: I don't think that we're on the same page yet. What I was asking was why this would even produce non-integers at all. For instance, if we were to take $x=10$, we would get a factor of $5$ in that $x+5=15$ and a factor of two in $x+2=12$, so we would indeed get an integer as a result.

Comment: It is true that the example you mentioned does not produce non-integers. What I am trying is to say in my post is that in general if you start with some $F(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]$ and divide it by some $5^m2^l$ to get an $f(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$, then whether $f(n)$ is integral will be periodic with respect to $n$, and the period divides $5^m2^l$.

Comment: Okay, I think that I sort of get what you're trying to say. Then, if that is the case, could you maybe provide a hard example so that I could test it out a bit, because I can't really seem to think of a definite example right now that would satisfy the problem. Thanks!

Comment: If $S = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ there does not exist a $f(x)$ such that $f(n)$ is integral if and only $n \pmod{10}$. But, for instance if $S = \{1,3,9\}$ an example is $f(x) = \frac{1}{10}(6x^3+2x^2-x+3)$. You can check this by looking at the patterns modulo 2 and modulo 5.

Comment: Actually, if that's the case, could this be extended to $S=\{1,5,6\}$? This would solve the problem after $x$ has been raised to the fourth power.

Comment: $\{1,5,6\}$ is also impossible. The closest remedy is $\{1,6\}$ or $\{0,1,5,6\}$. Please see the criterion in the second paragraph of the post.

Comment: So if $f(10k)$ is not an integer for some $k$ then, for some $m$, either $f(10k+2^m)$ or $f(10k+5^m)$ won't be an integer either. Nice!

Comment: More precisely, if $f(10k)$ is not either a 5-adic or a 2-adic integer etc....